# Do I have to rewrite cookie everytime I postback to retain it?

Tags: c#, cookies

I don't really understand the difference between request cookie and response cookie.  And it seem like everytime I postback, if I don't manually rewrite the cookie from request to response, then it disappears.  How do I solve this?

```
    public string getCookie(string name) {
        if (Request.Cookies["MyApp"] != null && Request.Cookies["MyApp"][name] != null) {
            return Request.Cookies["MyApp"][name];
        } else if (Response.Cookies["MyApp"] != null && Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name] != null) {
            return Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name];
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    public void writeCookie(string name, string value) {
        Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name] = value;
        HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
        newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.SetCookie(newCookie);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think cookies are lost if you do not rewrite them each time?

Comment: I don't get any value from getCookie if I don't rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Request.Cookies["MyApp"];
```

Code above will return you a cookie with name "MyApp" Doing this:

```
Request.Cookies["MyApp"][name]
```

You are taking value "name" from cookie called "MyApp".
But in your setCookie code you are setting a cookie with called `name` and do not create a cookie called "MyApp":

```
 HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);
 newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
 Response.SetCookie(newCookie);
```

So, you should remove `["MyApp"]` from any place you have it, or you may do something like this in setCookie:

```
public void writeCookie(string name, string value) {
        if(Response.Cookies["MyApp"] == null) {
            HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie("MyApp");
            newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
            Response.SetCookie(newCookie);
        }
        if(Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name] == null)
            Response.Cookies["MyApp"].Values.Add(name, value);
        else
            Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name] = val;
       // or maybe simple                 Response.Cookies["MyApp"][name] = val; will work fine, not sure here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request` is the "thing" you get when the user tries to get to your website, while `Response` is a way of responding to this request.

In other words, see the official msdn documentation, namely this part:

> ASP.NET includes two intrinsic cookie collections. The collection
>   accessed through the Cookies collection of HttpRequest contains
>   cookies transmitted by the client to the server in the Cookie header.
>   The collection accessed through the Cookies collection of HttpResponse
>   contains new cookies created on the server and transmitted to the
>   client in the Set-Cookie header.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx

So no, you don't have to create new cookies every time, unless they have already expired. Just be sure you reference the right collection of cookies.

Comment: Do I have to manually define the domain?  It seem the Request.Cookies.Domain is null

Comment: I believe if you do not define it, it gets a default value. I'm not sure if ASP.NET provides that default or if the browser does. You can easily read the cookies saved by your browser to see exactly what's being saved.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the domain and path that are being assigned to the cookie. It could be that your saved cookies are just being orphaned because the path is too specific or because the wrong domain is being set.

Domain is the server name that the browser sees such as "yourdomain.com". If the cookie is set with a different domain than this then the browser will never send it back. Likewise, the path of the cookie is the path to the resource being requested such as "/forum/admin/index" etc. The cookie is sent for that location and all child locations, but not for parent locations. A cookie set for "/forum/admin/index" will not be sent if you're accessing a page that sits in the "/forum" directory.